# aggregate totals from one table into a new table

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table that has items ordered from our shopping site.  Each row has an item number and associated cart number.  So each cart number can have one or more item numbers associated with it.  We want to figure out the top 4-5 items that are usually ordered with a given item.  Like you would see on the big sites like Amazon, etc.  I am wondering if there is a query I can run that will create a table with exactly this data in it.  Or would I have to do in programming (C#, etc).  The new table would probably have 5 columns.  The first column would be the main item number and then 4 more columns of most frequently ordered item numbers.  If this is even possible, I imagine it being a complicated query, so I don't have anything to paste here to show what I have started.

Here is a snip of the table with the relevant data.  Is there any other info that is required?

[image]

And here is a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b88417/1

Comment: This is most definitely possible and you wouldn't need to make a table for this, you could make a query that retrieves this. but you have to give us more information and also show what you've tried.

Comment: Added snip of table.  I can honestly say this is as far as I have gotten because I don't know how I would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work, if you could make an sql fiddle it might be easier to test:

```
SELECT s1.itemRef,
       s2.itemRef,
       COUNT(s2.itemRef) AS count_items
FROM    `cart_numbers` AS s1
JOIN    `cart_numbers` AS s2 ON s2.cartNumber = s1.cartNumber
WHERE s2.itemref != s1.itemref
AND s1.cartNumber = 129009
GROUP BY s2.itemRef
ORDER BY COUNT(s2.itemRef) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Updated query, this will retrieve a maximum of 5 products that are often bought with a product in the shopping cart

Comment: This is great help.  I forgot about SQL Fiddle.  Here is my data with your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b88417/1  But it doesn't list the associated item numbers with each item.

Comment: I need the original itemRef and then 4 more itemRefs for the 4 most frequently purchased together items in each row.

Comment: my query is actually a bit wrong, working on it now. (have to drive 20 min first) do you want the items based on a shopping cart or based on one single item?

Comment: need a row with 5 item numbers; the main item number and 4 associated item numbers, so i guess based on single item

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: i edited my query it works correctly now for a shopping cart i think, i have to go home now. i'll be happy to help some more in a bit, in the mean time you can try some stuff yourself and see if you understand what happens in this query!

Comment: This is wonderful, I simply changed `AND s1.cartNumber = 129009` to `AND s1.itemRef = 20093` and it appears to giving me the 5 items most purchased with 20093.  Exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you tons!

Comment: nice ^^ good job. glad to be of help! if you ever have another question you can always tag me in a comment so i get notified :) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select itemRef, count(*) as bought
from Orders 
where itemRef <> @item and cartNumber in 
(select cartNumber from Orders where itemRef = @item)
group by itemRef
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: This produces 0 results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b88417/2